# validate and compare dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to compare two dates in the following formats

a) Date1  - 01 Feb 2019 and second is

b) Date2  - 2/3/2017

I need to ensure that they cater to invalid dates and Date1 > date 2

```
function ValidateDates()
{

    var Date1 =" 01 Feb 2019";
    var Date2 ="2/3/2017";
    if(new Date(Date1) > new Date(Date2))
   {
     console.log("Date1 is greater");
   }

}
```

I am not looking for a script library like moment . Just want a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Your Script works. If you want to add a validation you could check out this: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php

Comment: whats problem. Your script works

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.parse(endDate) > Date.parse(startDate)
```